# How to make spring matrix variables work when request path template parameter is not the last in path and deploying to WebLogic 12.1.1?

Tags: spring-mvc, weblogic12c

I've been trying to use a matrix variable to provide additional information conceptually belonging to the request path parameter of a form "/path/{param}/someotherpath".
The application was configured to enable support for matrix variables (which is off by default).
However it still did not work out, so I created a simplified test case in the spring pitclinic sample application based on the sample code provided on the Spring MVC reference page:

```
@Controller
public class MatrixTestController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/matrix/test/{petId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String findPet(@PathVariable String petId, 
            @MatrixVariable(required=false, defaultValue="1") int q,
            Model model) {
        System.out.println("petId=" + petId + ", q=" + q);
        model.addAttribute("petId", petId);
        model.addAttribute("q", q);
        return "matrixtest";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/matrix/test/{petId}/paws", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String findPet2(@PathVariable String petId, 
            @MatrixVariable(required=false, defaultValue="1") int q,
            Model model) {
        System.out.println("petId=" + petId + ", q=" + q);
        model.addAttribute("petId", petId);
        model.addAttribute("q", q);
        return "matrixtest";
    }
}
```

The requests to both methods succeeded for Tomcat (the value for q was properly overwritten from its default value):

```
http://localhost:8084/spring-petclinic/matrix/test/1;q=2
http://localhost:8084/spring-petclinic/matrix/test/1;q=2/paws
```

However, for WebLogic only the request to the first method succeeded:

```
http://localhost:7001/spring-petclinic/matrix/test/1;q=3
```

The request to the second one resulted in Error 404--Not Found page:

```
http://localhost:7001/spring-petclinic/matrix/test/1;q=2/paws
```

The second request mapping is the request mapping I would actually like to use in the real application.

The only thing I found so far that looks related to the problem (however is not related to Spring) is a page from 2011 (related to an older version of WebLogic):
 http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2011/04/22/java-servlets-uri-parameters/
which states:

> Tomcat is the only container that understands that each segment of the path can have parameters. All the others assume the parameters can only appear on the last segment.

I did not find any information considering the use of matrix variables when deploying to WebLogic on the Spring MVC reference page (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-matrix-variables).
I neither did find anything that looked related in the description of weblogic.xml deployment descriptor in regard to semicolons in the URLs.

Is there anything else I might overlook? Is there perhaps a Spring configuration parameter which needs to be additionally enabled for WebLogic?

---

### The configuration

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping()
    {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        handlerMapping.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
        return handlerMapping;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter()
    {
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter handlerApapter = super.requestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        handlerApapter.setIgnoreDefaultModelOnRedirect(true);
        return handlerApapter;
    }
}
```

mvc-core-config.xml (just the change):

```
<!--    <mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>-->
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService" enable-matrix-variables="true" />
<!-- Used to change configuration for RequestMappingHandlerMapping removeSemicolonContent property which is needed for matrix variables support: -->
<bean class="WebConfig"/>
```

weblogic.xml (to be able to deploy to WebLogic):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
        <debug>true</debug>
    </jsp-descriptor>
    <context-root>/spring-petclinic</context-root>
    <container-descriptor>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
            <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
    </container-descriptor>
    <dispatch-policy>
</weblogic-web-app>
```